# Is it possible for CodeTwo to choose a server-side signature based on the mail's language?

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, entra-domain-services

I wasn't sure if this was the correct place for this question but here goes.

I want CodeTwo (With Azure) to fetch a certain signature based on the mail's language content.

Is this possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks for any replies :)

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do that. You could create a separate signature rule for every language you're going to use, then either use recipient filter to automatically add signatures based on the domain name (.fr, .de), or use keywords in a specific language to trigger a signature rule. You can take a look at [this guide](https://www.codetwo.com/userguide/email-signatures-for-office-365/signatures-in-different-languages.htm) for more information.

Comment: That's the way I've seen on the CodeTwo website, however - since most of our recipients have a .com domain, and getting everyone to use specific keywords wouldn't go easy   with the senior workers, I was hoping for a different solution. Nonetheless, thank you kindly for the response :)

Comment: Keywords can be used in another way - you could create a rule which would trigger a German signature if a common German word is found within the email thread. For example, if freundliche or grüße is found - this rule will be applied, if not - the general, English signature would be added. At this moment, that's as close as you can get to automating this. Another option is to use client-side signatures and let the users choose the right signature.